# How to fix a program that only works once?

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk

```
    def check_answer(self, currentscore):
    self.user_entry = self.user_entry.get_text()
    if self.user_entry == self.books:
        self.current += 1
        self.total += 1
        self.currentscore = self.current
        print "right"
    else:
        print "wrong"
        print self.currentscore
        print self.total
```

When i run it and i put text a second time is says `File "C:\Python27\guessing.py", line 16, in check_answer
    self.user_entry = self.user_entry.get_text()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_text'`
Could someone explain it to me. Why it to me why it only works once. and also why doesn't the program execute the if statement. It only says wrong.

`self.books = 'hello'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the variable holding the reference to the text box with its contents. So when `check_answer` runs for the first time, `self.user_entry` is your text box, and you can call its method `get_text()` to retrieve the text entered by the user. Unfortunately, you assign this text to the same variable (`self.user_entry =`) - so you loose the reference to the text box. After the first call, `self.user_entry` is a string (instance of `str` class) retrieved at the first call.

Use a different variable name, like this:

```
def check_answer(self, currentscore):
    self.user_entry_text = self.user_entry.get_text()
    if self.user_entry_text == self.books:
        self.current += 1
        self.total += 1
        self.currentscore = self.current
        print "right"
    else:
        print "wrong"
        print self.currentscore
        print self.total
```

Also, possibly it doesn't have to be class's field, so you can also skip the `self.` part. In such case you could use the same name (`user_entry`), but for sake of readability it's better to call a variable with a name that says precisely what the variable holds:

```
    user_entry_text = self.user_entry.get_text()
    if user_entry_text == self.books:
```